SharePoint 2013 how to pass URL with parameters for refreshing page after close a page
I has got this code. I want to pass a url with parameters to refresh the page after the popup close. Could You please tell me how to do this ?
If I pass this code it refresh me a page but without my parameters from url and i must reload it page again.
  function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
    
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
    
    }

I need to redirect after close popup to page like this after closing popup:
www.google.pl?ClaimId=35

You can try this:
function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
    if(dialogResult === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
    {
       window.location.href ="http://www.google.pl/?ClaimId=35";
    }   
}

